Session storage not done properly in playwright
Trying to run cucumber scenarios in parallel. However the implementation is actually not working fine. When I run the command yarn cucumber-js path-to-feature.feature --parallel 4, all four tests are performing the login operation. However when I do parallel 2 then the first 2 tests login & the other tests in the feature file use the captured session storage.
Could some one who has faced a similar problem before please suggest a solution. I ideally want all the tests to use the session storage & reduce the test execution time as we have a suite of 400+ UI tests
This is my hooks.js file
Before(async function (scenario) {
  log(`Starting Scenario: ${scenario.pickle.name}`)
  this.browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
    channel: 'chrome',
    headless: false,
    isEnabled: () => true,
    log: logWrapper
  })

  const contextOptions = fs.existsSync(sessionStatePath) ? { storageState: sessionStatePath } : {}
  const context = await this.browser.newContext({
    ...contextOptions,
    permissions: ['clipboard-read', 'clipboard-write'],
    recordVideo: { dir: 'videos/' }
  })

  await context.setDefaultTimeout(60000)
  this.page = await context.newPage()
  this.poManager = new PageObjectManager(this.page)
  this.loginPage = await this.poManager.fetchLoginPage()
  this.landingPage = await this.poManager.fetchLandingPage()
  this.apiContext = await playwright.request.newContext()
  this.apiUtil = new APIUtil(this.apiContext)
  this.dataGenerator = new DataGenerator(this.apiContext)
  this.backEndHelper = new BackEndHelper(this.apiUtil)

  if (!contextOptions.storageState) {
    await this.loginPage.gotoLoginPage()
    await this.loginPage.loginToTheApplication()
    await this.landingPage.closeModalDialog()
    await context.storageState({ path: sessionStatePath })
    this.jwtToken = await this.apiUtil.getjwtToken(await this.loginPage.fetchPassCode())
    log('Session state has been saved.')
  }
})


Wait. Cucumber or Playwright??

It uses playwright as the automation tool & cucumber for BDD testing
